# How to use mypy annotation in a for loop with generic subclassing / inheritance?

Tags: python, stub, mypy

I am stuck with python mypy inheritance and for loop.

To simplify here is a valid stub for stubs/xml/__init__.pyi :

```
from typing import Dict,Iterable,Sized,Iterator,List,Optional, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='Element')


class Element():
    attrib: Dict[str,str]

    def getchildren(self)->List[T]:...
    def getparent(self)->List[Element]:...
    def drop(self)->None:...
```

Here is a valid stub for son element in stubs/xml/html/__init__.pyi

```
from typing import Sized,Dict,Type,Generic
from xml import Element
import xml

class HtmlElement(xml.Element):...
```

Here is the code that I am not able to correct : the last exemple is making mypy complain, which is quiet problematic

```
from typing import List, Dict, Set, Optional, Tuple

from xml.html import HtmlElement
from xml import Element
import xml
import xml.html

a: HtmlElement = HtmlElement()
b: HtmlElement = HtmlElement()

# getparent return ->List[Element]
d: List[Element] = a.getparent()
for d_element in d:
    d_element.drop() # Mypy is ok

for f_element in b.getparent():
    f_element.drop() # Mypy is ok

# getchildren return ->List[T] 
c: List[HtmlElement] = a.getchildren()
for a_element in c:
    a_element.drop()  #Mypy is ok

b_element: HtmlElement # requested by mypy 'Need type annotation for 'b_element'
for b_element in b.getchildren():
    b_element.drop() # Mypy is complaining with : <nothing> has no attribute "drop"
```

Mypy does not seems to understand the pre typing when type is generic, when it work in all other cases.

How to use mypy annotation in this for loop with generic subclassing / inheritance ? Is that a mypy bug, or am I missing something ?

Note that this is a Mypy (ie, Python annotation checking) question. The real implementation of the method is not the subject of this question.

Comment: might be an issue with `HTMLElement`. Does something like this work: `b_element: HtmlElement = HtmlElement()` ?

Comment: Can you make sure the drop method is implemented in the ```HtmlElement``` Class?

Comment: @keval, this is not about implementation. Mypy is about annotating Python and having 'compilation' like error. So my question is about the Mypy error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with your definition of `getchildren` in `Element`.

That function is annotated to return some generic TypeVar -- but TypeVar of what, exactly? It's impossible for mypy to deduce what T is supposed to be there. An Element? Some subclass of Element?

You should either stop using TypeVars entirely and have that return a `List[Element]` or make the `Element` class generic.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Dict, List

T = TypeVar('T', bound='Element')

class Element(Generic[T]):
    attrib: Dict[str,str]

    def getchildren(self) -> List[T]: ...
    def getparent(self) -> List[Element]: ...
    def drop(self) -> None: ...
```

If we add back the type hints to the `self` argument we normally omit, this would mean we've turned the signature of `getchildren` from `def getchildren(self: Element) -> List[T]` into `def getchildren(self: Element[T]) -> List[T]`. The latter signature satisfies the rule that you must always use a TypeVar at least twice in all function and method signatures you write.

And of course, propagate the generic when you subclass `HTMLElement` and use either type in your code.